# LINQ join producing null reference error suddenly

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ query which has the below joins

```
join v in dc.Vehicles on c.VehicleReg equals v.VehicleReg into vg
from v in vg.DefaultIfEmpty()
join vt in dc.VehicleTypes on v.VehicleType equals vt.ID into vtg
from vt in vtg.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Now this worked perfect before, but it seems all of a sudden it's returning an object reference error trying to join vehicle into vehicletype when *v* is null.  This worked before, and had the effect of making vtg null - which is ideal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you are still using linq-to-sql? The reason why it worked before and doesn't work at the moment can be because before you used linq-to-sql translated to SQL and now you are using linq-to-objects.

Comment: Interesting - I did make a custom IQueryable extension, but I weren't aware this would change it to LINQ-to-Objects

Comment: Show your extension method perhaps we can find the problem ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer would probable filter null Vehicles

join v in dc.Vehicles.Where(v => v != null) on c.VehicleReg equals v.VehicleReg into vg

Hope that helps